# Checking for a matching entry within a file

Tags: macros, input

I have a file containing a list, like this:

```
apple
orange
pear
pineapple
```

How can I create a macro which checks if an item is on that list. E.g.:

- `\isfruit{pear}` returns "1".
- `\isfruit{carrot}` returns "0".

Comment: The package `etoolbox` provides the macro `\ifinlist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is not overly long, you can do with

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newread\@readisfruit
\newcommand\isfruit[3][]{%
  \begingroup\endlinechar=\m@ne
  \openin\@readisfruit=#2
  \def\@tempa{#3}%
  \def\@result{0}%
  \loop\unless\ifeof\@readisfruit
    \read\@readisfruit to \@tempb
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb\def\@result{1}\fi
  \repeat             
  \closein\@readisfruit
  \edef\x{\endgroup\if!\noexpand#1!\@result\else\edef\noexpand#1{\@result}\fi}\x}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\isfruit{village.dat}{pear}

\isfruit[\result]{village.dat}{carrot}\show\result

\end{document}
```

It's not expandable, though, so I've provided an optional argument: a control sequence name where to store the result.

### Alternative definition

As Ahmed Musa observes, if the file is long, reading it can be very time consuming, especially if the test is performed many times. We can exploit **catchfile**:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\village}{village.dat}{\endlinechar=`| }
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\isfruitA}[3][]{%
  \ifcsname loaded@#2\endcsname\else
    \expandafter\CatchFileDef\csname loaded@#2\endcsname{#2}{\endlinechar=`| }%
  \fi
  \begingroup\expandafter\let\expandafter\@tempa\csname loaded@#2\endcsname
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{\unexpanded{#3}|}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@tempa}}}\x
  \ifin@ \def\@result{1}\else \def\@result{0}\fi
  \if!\noexpand#1!\@result\else\edef#1{\@result}\fi}
\makeatother
```

Now `\isfruitA{village.dat}{pear}` will print 1 (after having defined a macro expanding to the contents of `village.dat`, with lines separated by `|`, which we assume does not appear in the strings). If we call

```
\isfruitA[\result]{village.dat}{orange}
```

the result of the test (0 or 1) will be put in the macro `\result`. The file will be read just once. Some package such as **xstrings** could be used to avoid the cumbersome test with `\ifin@`.

Comment: For everyone who doesn't know the command `\m@ne`: `\m@ne=-1`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I should have said it. Thanks.

Comment: I need to search the file thousands of times, however, I will only search each word one time. Does this second method still help me speed up the search and do I still need to use `result` for that?

Comment: What kind of data is the "0" or "1"? I tried using `\ifnumequal{\isfruitA{village.dat}{orange}}{1}{is on list}{not on list}` as part of other checks, but it cannot interpret the "0" or "1". Using `ifstrequal` also failed.

Comment: @Village The test is *not* expandable, as stated in the answer. You can do `\isfruitA[\result]{village.dat}{orange}` and then `\ifnumequal{\result}{1}{true}{false}`

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer this question. Maybe somebody is able to improve my answer.

I created the macro `\isfruit` in this way that the macro reads the file during the `enlinechar` is set to `-1`. Every line will be read and saved in a list. After this I compare the list with an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{fruit.tex}
apple
orange
pear
pineapple
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newread\InputFruit
\newcommand*\isfruit[2]{%
     \begingroup%
      \def\MyList{}
      \openin\InputFruit=#1
       \endlinechar=-1%
       \loop\unless\ifeof\InputFruit
        \read\InputFruit to \reserveda
         \listxadd\MyList{\reserveda}
        \repeat
        \closein\InputFruit
      \xifinlist{#2}{\MyList}{in list}{not in list}
    \endgroup%
     }%
\begin{document}
\isfruit{fruit.tex}{apple}

\isfruit{fruit.tex}{foo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Marco Daniel: There are spaces in your macro that aren't nullified by the internal `\endlinechar=-1`. They will show up in the document in horizontal mode. Moreover, the assignment `\endlinechar=-1%` shoud have been `\endlinechar=-1 %`. Also, I will take the branching of `\xifinlist` outside the `\isfruit` command, to give the user of `\isfruit` the opportunity to change the two callbacks. And your list separator (as used by default in `\xifinlist`) may be present in the original list to be tested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{fruit.tex}
apple
orange
pear
pineapple
\end{filecontents*}
\begingroup
\catcode`\|=3
\endlinechar=-1
\makeatletter
\gdef\ifinfruitlist#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar=-1
  \def\MyList{}
  \openin\@inputcheck=#1 %
  \loop\unless\ifeof\@inputcheck
    \read\@inputcheck to \reserveda
    \edef\MyList{\ifx\MyList\@empty\else
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\MyList}|
      \fi\unexpanded\expandafter{\reserveda}}
  \repeat
  \closein\@inputcheck
  \@expandtwoargs\in@{|#2|}{|\unexpanded\expandafter{\MyList}|}
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifin@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\ifinfruitlist{fruit.tex}{apple}{in list}{not in list}
\ifinfruitlist{fruit.tex}{foo}{in list}{not in list}
\end{document
```

The above solution is unacceptably inefficient. If the list is ten pages long and the token of interest is the first one in the list, we have to first read the entire document before checking for the presence of the test string. Here is a more efficient implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{fruit.tex}
apple
orange
pear
pineapple
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\gdef\ifinfruitlist#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\reserved@b{#2}%
  \endlinechar=-1 %
  \openin\@inputcheck=#1 %
  \@tempswafalse\@testfalse
  \def\do{%
    \if@tempswa
      \closein\@inputcheck
    \else
      \ifeof\@inputcheck
        \@tempswatrue
      \else
        \read\@inputcheck to\reserved@a
        \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b
          \@testtrue\@tempswatrue
        \fi
      \fi
      \expandafter\do
    \fi
  }%
  \do
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \if@test\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ifinfruitlist{fruit.tex}{pear}{in list}{not in list}
\ifinfruitlist{fruit.tex}{foo}{in list}{not in list}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I don't think the @ notation in the answers sends a notification but in comments it will... So am adding this comment so that Marco gets notified.

Comment: @AhmedMUsa: +1 You are right.

Answer (score 3):

LuaTeX is ideally suited for such a task. Below is a luatex based solution in ConTeXt.

```
\startbuffer[fruits]
apple
orange
pear
pineapple
\stopbuffer

%% Save the contents of fruits buffer in \jobname-fruits.tmp
\savebuffer[fruits][fruits] 

\startluacode
  local data = {}
  local find = string.find
  function commands.doiffruitelse(file, fruit)
      if not data[file] then
          data[file] = io.loaddata(file) or ""
      end
      return commands.testcase(find(data[file], "%f[%a]"..fruit.."%f[%A]") ~= nil)
  end
\stopluacode

\def\doiffruitelse#1%
    {\ctxcommand{doiffruitelse("\jobname-fruits.tmp", "#1")}}

\def\isFruit#1%
    {\doiffruitelse{#1}{1}{0}}

\starttext
\startlines
\isFruit{pear}
\isFruit{carrot}
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

This uses `io:loaddata()` function from `l-io.lua` to load the contents of a file, the `commands` table for namespace separation of lua commands, and `commands.testcase` function to provide do-if-else functionality. The actual match is done using `string.find` function. I use the [Frontier Pattern](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FrontierPattern) to match word boundaries.